# How can I implement a firebase set request within a call back

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to node js and I would like to write information within a callback function to my firebase database.

I've been searching and it seems that the callback is asynchronous. How can I use firestore in this callback?

```
    exports.registerRestaurantPayout = functions.firestore.document('*********')
  .onCreate(async (paymentSnap, context) => {

    var request = require('request');

    var authCode = paymentSnap.data().auth_code;
    var firstString = 'client_secret=********&code=';
    var secondString = '&grant_type=authorization_code';
    var dataString = firstString + authCode + secondString;

    var options = {
        url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        body: dataString
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(body);

            return await firestore.document('***********')
              .set({'account': body}, {merge: true});
            //return await paymentSnap.ref.set({'account': body}, {merge: true});
        }else{


            //return await paymentSnap.ref.set({'error' : error}, { merge: true });
        }
    }

    request(options, callback);

  });
```

I get the following error Parsing error: Unexpected token firestore even though I can use firestore outside of the callback. The specific problem is the return statement in the callback

Comment: Is your code part of a Cloud Function? If yes, could you please add the entire code of the Cloud Function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for your reply, I've just updated the code and yes it is part od a cloud function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Cloud Function you should use promises to handle asynchronous tasks (like the HTTP call to the stripe API, or the write to the Realtime Database). By default `request` does not return promises, so you need to use an interface wrapper for request, like [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise), and adapt your code along the following lines:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

exports.registerRestaurantPayout = functions.firestore.document('*********')
 .onCreate((paymentSnap, context) => {

   var authCode = paymentSnap.data().auth_code;
   var firstString = 'client_secret=**********=';
   var secondString = '&grant_type=authorization_code';
   var dataString = firstString + authCode + secondString;


   var options = { 
     method: 'POST',
     uri: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
     body: dataString,
     json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
   };

   return rp(options)
   .then(parsedBody => {
       return paymentSnap.ref.set({'account': parsedBody}, {merge: true});
   })
   .catch(err => {
       return paymentSnap.ref.set({'error' : err}, { merge: true });
   });

});
```

---

I would also suggest that you watch the two following "must see" videos from the Firebase team, about Cloud Functions and promises: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I will also take a look at the videos.