# Using Firebase Callable Functions with 3rd Party APIs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to use Firebase's callable functions to make a post request to a Stripe endpoint. Only thing I'm getting back on the client is the object with the `message` property on it that says "This is a test". I'm not even sure how to tell if the request to Stripe is firing or how to log any response from Stripe. The only thing I see in the Firebase logs are the `data` and `context` arguments I'm sending from the client. How can I go about debugging this post request and getting a response back from the Stripe API?

NOTE: I'm on the Blaze plan.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require('request');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.stripeAuth = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('DATA', data);
  console.log('CONTEXT', context);

  request.post(({
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    url: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_secret: "CLIENT_SECRET",
      code: data.authCode,
      grant_type: "authorization_code"
    })
  }), (error, response, body) => {
    response = resoponse;
    body = body;
    if (error) {
      return error
    }

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log('BODY', JSON.parse(body))
      return JSON.parse(body);
    }
  })

  return { message: "This is a test" }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a firebase set request within a call back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449389/how-can-i-implement-a-firebase-set-request-within-a-call-back)

Comment: You're going to have to learn how to use JavaScript promises to track asynchronous work in your function, and return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.

Comment: Do you want to use stripe on cloud functions?  Would you try 
 this sample? https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe